# line with vector and labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello how can I represent this type of vector with labels?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of patience, there is some tools as Mathcha https://www.mathcha.io/editor where you can draw your beautiful image with `TikZ`. It should be remembered that this tool like Geogebra does not always produce good results (see the long code). The advice is to read and study the manual of `TikZ`...but if you don't have time this can sometimes be useful.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Straight Lines [id:da6137486785624535] 
\draw    (119,195) -- (330.55,147.44) ;
\draw [shift={(332.5,147)}, rotate = 527.3299999999999] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-4.9) .. controls (6.95,-2.3) and (3.31,-0.67) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.67) and (6.95,2.3) .. (10.93,4.9)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da46366121878923283] 
\draw    (152.75,187.75) -- (237.23,84.55) ;
\draw [shift={(238.5,83)}, rotate = 489.3] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-4.9) .. controls (6.95,-2.3) and (3.31,-0.67) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.67) and (6.95,2.3) .. (10.93,4.9)   ;

%Straight Lines [id:da030080067558663437] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}]  (238.5,83) -- (261.5,162) ;


%Straight Lines [id:da5041853499131848] 
\draw    (152.75,187.75) -- (259.55,162.46) ;
\draw [shift={(261.5,162)}, rotate = 526.6800000000001] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-4.9) .. controls (6.95,-2.3) and (3.31,-0.67) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.67) and (6.95,2.3) .. (10.93,4.9)   ;

%Shape: Circle [id:dp6722912642446035] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (237.5,80.63) .. controls (237.5,79.31) and (238.56,78.25) .. (239.88,78.25) .. controls (241.19,78.25) and (242.25,79.31) .. (242.25,80.63) .. controls (242.25,81.94) and (241.19,83) .. (239.88,83) .. controls (238.56,83) and (237.5,81.94) .. (237.5,80.63) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp08004645069916183] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (151.75,186.75) .. controls (151.75,185.44) and (152.81,184.38) .. (154.13,184.38) .. controls (155.44,184.38) and (156.5,185.44) .. (156.5,186.75) .. controls (156.5,188.06) and (155.44,189.13) .. (154.13,189.13) .. controls (152.81,189.13) and (151.75,188.06) .. (151.75,186.75) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (174,133) node    {$\overline{u}$};
% Text Node
\draw (214,192) node    {$\overline{u}'$};
% Text Node
\draw (267,121) node    {$\overline{u}''$};
% Text Node
\draw (267,70) node    {$P\equiv(1,-1,1)$};
% Text Node
\draw (330,178) node    {$\overline{v}\equiv(1,-1,2)$};
% Text Node
\draw (153,205) node    {$A\equiv(1,2,0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a projection from 3d to the screen. Given appropriate basis vectors, one can reproduce the depicted triangle using the given coordinates. There is no need to use different coordinates. For the projection one can simply use `(P|-A)`, no library is needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0,0)},y={(-1cm,-4cm/3)},z={(1cm,-2cm)},thick,auto]
 \draw[-stealth]  (1,2,0) 
     node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below:{$A\colon(1,2,0)$}] (A){} 
     -- node[sloped] {$\bar u$} 
     (1,-1,1) coordinate[label=above right:{$P\colon(1,-1,1)$}](P);
 \draw[dashed] (P) -- node{$\bar u''$} (P|-A);
 \path (A)  -- node[swap]{$\bar u'$} (P|-A);
 \draw[-stealth] (1,2,0) -- (1,-1,2)
    coordinate[label=below right:{$v\colon(1,-1,2)$}](v);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. No, this does not become "more elegant" if one uses the `quotes` library.

Comment: Beautiful!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

- inspired by @Sebastiano answer (+1), but drawn without help of any drawing tools,
- considering coordinates `A`, `P` and `V` gives image very different from showed in question, so I decide to redraw it (as @Sebastiano do)
- at drawing first base line, than projection on base line, and dashed line orthogonal to baseline and on end vector `u` (note: image reproduce showed image and not consider coordinates for points `A`, `V` and `P`):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = {Stealth},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=4pt, 
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
              node contents={}},
                        ]
% mimic showed image,
% not considered coordinates noted on image
% used are relative polar coordinates
\draw[-{Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 3]}]   
    (0,0) -- ++ (15:5);
\draw[->, semithick]
    (15:1)  node (A) [dot,label=below right:{A=(1,2,0)}] 
        to["$\vec{u}'$",sloped] ++ (15:3) coordinate[label=below right:{V=(1,-1,2)}] (V);
\draw[->, dashed] 
    (V) to["$\vec{u}''$",sloped] ($(V)!2.4cm!270:(A)$) 
                                          coordinate[label=right:{P=(1,-1,2)}] (P);
\draw[->, thick] 
    (A) to["$\vec{u}$",sloped] (P);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankkk you for the "nomination" :-)